# Jquery click event function is can't download csv file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

At the first , I export csv file by html `onclick` element !It was working.When I change it to jquery click event for some reason ! It is can't export csv file ? Why, I think the same function is called !

> Export.Export() is for my csv file downloading function.

This code can download csv file

```
<a href="" class="button" onclick="Export.Export.apply(this, [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);">Export</a>
```

This is not working

```
<a href="" class="export">Export</a>
<script>
  $('.export').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     alert("click");//click
     Export.Export.apply($(this), [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);
     });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `'.export'` is for jquery to search by `class`

Comment: What is the error are you seeing? Do you see the `alert`?

Comment: ops sorry doesn't see your second href, is it `Export.Export()` is a jquery function?

Comment: What is the first parameter for `Export.apply(parameter1,parameter2)` for?

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: Try `Export.Export.apply(this, [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);`.. Not sure which `this` context this function is expecting..

Comment: `parameter1` is table id for grab tbody data and `parameter2` is filename

Comment: In the jquery code - `apply(this,` not `$(this)`, but it shouldn't be needed on the `onclick=`

Comment: Why do you need `.apply()` at all?  Just call the function?

Comment: both `this & $(this)` is not worked

Comment: If no error in console,you can try change to  `$('.export').on('click',function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the click event is bound before all the scripts are loaded..

try :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.export').click(function(e){
        Export.Export.apply($(this), [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `<a href="#" class="button" onclick="Export.Export.apply(this, [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);">Export</a>`, Hope it should work. Make sure you script is loaded after the  tag is loaded.

If href is blank the current page will be reloaded before calling the click event, So the page will be refreshed before downloading the file.

Comment: __"href cannot be left blank"__ Where did you get this ?

Answer (score -1):

I'd never use an anchor-tag together with `$(element).click(function(){});`. How about using

```
<button onclick="exportcsv(this);">Export</button>
<script>
  function exportcsv(e){
    var $e = $(e);
    Export.Export.apply($e, [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what will be different with my first working code `onclick="Export.Export.apply(this, [$('table.listtbl'), 'Table.csv']);"`

Comment: Nothing, I guess (only that you'd have a propper html-formatting). But then: Why di you need to change it?